# WordPress, how can I get the ID of the picture that I upload?

Tags: wordpress

I need to upload a picture, and use it. But I can't find out the ID of the picture. What can I do now?

```
<form class="avatar-form" name="avatar_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" class="avatar" name="avatar" />
  <input type="submit" class="avatar-submit" name="avatar_submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Or if someone can get the url of the upload picture?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    // get the file suffix
    $suffix = pathinfo($file['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    // define the save location and filename
    $filename = $user_name.'-'.date('YmdHis').'.'.$suffix;
    $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $path = $wp_upload_dir['path'].'/'.$filename;

    // upload file
    if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $path)) {
        $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment(array(
            'guid'              =>  $wp_upload_dir['url'].'/'.$filename,
            'post_mime_type'    =>  $file['type'],
            'post_title'        =>  preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', $filename),
            'post_content'      =>  '',
            'post_status'       =>  'inherit',
        ), $path, get_the_ID());

        // Make sure that this file is included, as wp_generate_attachment_metadata() depends on it.
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );

        // Generate the metadata for the attachment, and update the database record.
        $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $path);
        wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

    }
```

We can make the uploaded picture as attachment. So that the $attach_id is the picture ID.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I have understood the question correctly. You have uploaded an image to Wordpress and would like the ID or the URL of that image?

The URL is simple to get. Just go to the upload library and hoover over the image and you will see the url.

Regarding the ID it is more complicated. One suggestion I found after googling is to create a function to get the ID.

```
function pn_get_attachment_id_from_url( $attachment_url = '' ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $attachment_id = false;

    // If there is no url, return.
    if ( '' == $attachment_url )
        return;

    // Get the upload directory paths
    $upload_dir_paths = wp_upload_dir();

    // Make sure the upload path base directory exists in the attachment URL, to verify that we're working with a media library image
    if ( false !== strpos( $attachment_url, $upload_dir_paths['baseurl'] ) ) {

        // If this is the URL of an auto-generated thumbnail, get the URL of the original image
        $attachment_url = preg_replace( '/-\d+x\d+(?=\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$)/i', '', $attachment_url );

        // Remove the upload path base directory from the attachment URL
        $attachment_url = str_replace( $upload_dir_paths['baseurl'] . '/', '', $attachment_url );

        // Finally, run a custom database query to get the attachment ID from the modified attachment URL
        $attachment_id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT wposts.ID FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id AND wpostmeta.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file' AND wpostmeta.meta_value = '%s' AND wposts.post_type = 'attachment'", $attachment_url ) );

    }

    return $attachment_id;}
```

I have not tried it my self but found it here;
https://philipnewcomer.net/2012/11/get-the-attachment-id-from-an-image-url-in-wordpress/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I find the function `wp_insert_attachment()`, and solve it. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment